How to change maximum execution time with MS Access&MySQL Connector/ODBC
In MS Access, By right-clicking on the [Table] pane and selecting [Import] -> [ODBC Database], importing source data into a new table in the current database.
When using the MySQL ODBC 8.0 Unicode Driver to import tables smaller than 200MB in row file format, the error "[MySQL][ODBC 8.0(w) Driver][mysqld-{version}-log]Query execution was interrupted, maximum statement execution time exceeded (#3024)" frequently occurs.
Since the MySQL server we are connecting to does not have an execution time limit, i suspect that Access or the Driver is imposing this limit. What solutions can ensure a stable import process?
My environment is as follows:
Windows 10 Pro
Microsoft Access For Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2406 Build 16.0.17726.20078) 64-bit
.accdb 2007 - 2016 file format
MySQL ODBC 8.0 Unicode Driver
Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
The connection information screen for the MySQL Connector does not have a relevant setting option (including in Details), and setting SET @@session.max_execution_time = nnnnn in the Initial Statement and adding CommandTimeout DWORD in ODBCINST.INI did not work for me.
